# Understanding the "w+d" label in the output of iostat -s

Tags: command-line

The manual page of iotop fails to mention what the labels stand for when the output is modified by the -s (short) output. I can infer that they mean megabytes written per second and total, but I can't figure out what the +d stands for.

Here is the output:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           9.80    0.00    4.63   16.10    0.00   69.46

$ iostat -sm 3 /dev/md2 /dev/md4 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/sd{a,b,c,d}
(...)
Device             tps    MB_read/s     MB_w+d/s    MB_read     MB_w+d
md2            1096.00       273.58         0.33        820          1
md4            1339.33         0.00       319.25          0        957
nvme0n1           0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sda            1069.67        67.88         0.17        203          0
sdb             822.67         0.00       160.08          0        480
sdc            1078.00        68.90         0.17        206          0
sdd            1083.67        70.25         0.17        210          0
```

I think the + is there to indicate that the middle of the word has been removed, but the +d is puzzling to me. Please help me understand what the label means. This is what I think:

- Device: name of block device
- tps: transactions per second
- MB_read/s: megabytes per second read
- MB_w+d/s: megabytes per second written
- MB_read: sum during sample period
- MB_w+d: sum during sample period

What does the "+d" mean?!

- writed?
- wridden?
- wroted?
- written to disk?
- written oud?

...I don't get it :)

---

If anyone is curious, the labels / headers in the other two modes are:

```
default
Device      tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd

extended
Device      r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
```

Comment: Can you also show the output when `-s` is not specified? Is it iostat or iotop?

Comment: Have it your way.